# Meaning of “Il a fallu ce hasard”

Tags: sens

I was wondering about this phrase that I came across in the movie *Parapluies de Cherbourg*.

> Il a fallu ce hasard.

I understand the meaning — *This is unplanned* — but I am having a hard time parsing this sentence. For example why is *falloir* used here?

Could anyone please help? Also is this phrase of common use in French? 
EDIT:

The full context: Geneviève on meeting her long-lost lover:

> J'ai été chercher la petite chez ma belle mère, il a fallu ce hasard.

So based on the below answer could it mean that : this coincidence just had to be (in the sense of I'm glad I ran into you) . Or does it mean just mean that this coincidence was necessary for us to meet?

Comment: C'est ma première réponse ici mais je suis ce site depuis un petit temps maintenant. J'avoue que la qualité des réponses que je lis habituellement m'a un peu fait hésiter à poster la mienne, donc j'en ai fait un commentaire. Je suis en effet loin d'avoir toutes les références ou compétences que la plupart des intervenants ont... mais voilà mon erreur réparée :-)

Comment: @arun in case it's not clear from the answer below, there's no undertone of being glad (even though she might be in effect). It's pretty neutral, although some people could read a slight  implication of destiny.

Comment: D’après [cette source](http://profondeurdechamps.com/2012/02/25/super-ou-ordinaire/), les paroles de Geneviève sont plutôt: **«J’ai fait ce détour. Je ne pensais pas te rencontrer, il a fallu ce hasard».**  Pour moi, ça veut dire que d’avoir «fait ce détour» est le hasard dont elle parle qu’il a fallu pour produire leur rencontre, donc Bartdude & sa réponse sont tout a fait correct en expliquant qu’il y avait des «missing parts/events» & en le traduisant comme «was needed»(& not as expressing gladness, although she had caused the "hasard" by purposely taking the detour in hopes of finding Guy)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your understanding of the meaning might not be 100% correct; This sentence might be better translated to :

> This unplanned event ("ce hasard") was needed so that another event
>   could happen.

But you're actually missing a second part in the French sentence, probably speaking about this "another event" :

> Il a fallu ce hasard *pour que nous nous rencontrions*

Answer (score 4):

C'est une phrase implicite, Il manque la suite de la phrase, elle est sous-entendue.
Elle est comme abrégée avec des points de suspensions.

La phrase normale, aurait dû être:
Il a fallu ce hasard pour.... que je le revois.

En anglais, ça donnerait quelque chose comme:
This coincidence was necessary to meet him again....

Mais ce que la phrase sous-entend, c'est l'idée de destin, de destinée:

Tu vois, normalement je n'aurais pas dû le revoir, mais il a fallu que le sort nous réunisse à nouveau (sort = destinée)

"Il a fallu" = sens de nécessité, mais ici, évoquant le destin, ça implique que c'est le destin qui décide, avec un sens de fatalité. On ne sait pas si la personne veut dire que c'était écrit, ou que c'est la malchance. ça peut vouloir dire les deux choses.